# how would I set up this layout?

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to put together this layout...

[image]

... but I'm having issues with the middle section.

The left section (with the MP3 icon) is **ALWAYS** aligned left and has fixed width of `72px`... the right section (with the READY text) is **ALWAYS** aligned right **BUT** but its width may vary, i.e. it is **not** fixed.

I want the middle section to be aligned to the left and span the width between the left & right sections **without** overlapping the right section. So if the text is obscenely long, it will wrap around to a second line instead of overlapping or pushing the right section down.

This is my basic structure so far...

```
<div id="files">
    <div class="file">
        <div class="file-icon"></div>
        <div class="file-status">
            <span class="file-status-text">READY 100%</span>
        </div>
        <div class="file-info">
            <div class="file-name">
                <span class="file-name-text"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How would I get this layout? Feel free to modify my HTML structure... it's just what I have so far, nothing is set in stone.

Comment: I'm not one to use tables for layout, but unless I'm missing something that certainly looks like tablular data to me. Columns of **File Type**, **File Name**, **File Status**

Comment: interesting... I always try to avoid using tables. StackOverflow doesn't use tables when they list questions... I'm trying to mimic something like that. I will give it a try though. would you mind providing an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here's a fiddle:

Here's the code:

### HTML

```
<div class="file">
    <div class="file-icon"></div>
    <div class="file-status">
        <span class="file-status-text"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="file-info">
        <div class="file-name">
            <span class="file-name-text"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="file-size">
            <span class="file-size-text"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.file {
    border-top: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
.file-icon {
    height: 100%;
    width: 72px;
    margin: 0px 16px;
    float: left;
}

.file-status {
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 72px;
    margin: 0px 16px;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
}

.file-status-text {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #666666;
    line-height: 100px;
}

.file-info {
    position: relative;
}

.file-name {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 36px;
}

.file-name-text {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #666666;
    line-height: 32px;
}

.file-size {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.file-size-text {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #727272;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this would require a lot of styling on your behave and would need to float a lot of elements. Currently busy right now but would have rigged it up for you. Put float left and float right and make sure those

```
<Music icon + info>
 <Music icon img>
  <info>
<read>
 <readytext>
```

that is my pseudo code for it.

Comment: no rush... i'd love to see your solution whenever you can get to it. i don't have a problem with styling... i'm just stuck on structure :/

Comment: just had an epiphany! i think i got it... will post back if i get it